# Dart - Allow SubType to Implement class method or else have it be null

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I specify that subtypes can implement a function if they want to, but if they don't implement it, it will be null?

I want to do this:

```
// base class member
Future<dynamic> vpSubmitLocalMethod()?;

// in a function in the same base class:

if (vpSubmitLocalMethod != null) {
  vpSubmitLocalMethod!();
}
```

Is this possible? Or if not, what is the cleanest solution? Or do I have to create an extra boolean class member to use in the if statement?

Comment: Ah, actually, if it is not possible, probably just make the function in the base class do absolutely nothing and call it without the if statements...maybe

Comment: A subType can override a method of its super-class. What is the problem here?

Comment: @EmreSURK The method is never null when using traditional method inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:
create

```
typedef SubmitLocal = Future Function();
```

In your class, create a field :

```
SubmitLocal? vpSubmitLocalMethod;
```

And you use :

```
vpSubmitLocalMethod?.call();
```

Comment: What syntax do I use to override the method in the subclass?

Comment: I think i would have to set the method inside a function such as a constructor by assigning it. So treat it like a variable which just doesn't really feel good.